# Finding MAX Date of Two Fields in an Access Query

Tags: ms-access, max

In my access database, we keep track of two sets of dates.  One set is for date of membership dues payments, the other set is date of other contributions (a non-membership donation.)  There are multiple dates for each person depending on number of payments made for each type.

```
Example:  
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | Dues_Date     | Cont_Date     | 
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | 01/01/15      | 09/12/11      | 
|    | 01/01/14      |               | 
|    | 01/01/13      |               |  
| 2  | 07/30/14      | 06/20/13      |  
|    |               | 11/12/11      |  
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

First I needed to know the most recent payment for each of the two fields so I ran a query that tells me the MAX (most recent) date for each field.

```
Example Query:  
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | Max Dues_Date | Max Cont_Date |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | 01/01/15      | 09/12/11      |
| 2  | 07/30/14      | 06/20/13      |
| 3  | 02/11/13      | 09/16/14      |
| 4  | 07/30/12      | 06/20/11      |
| 5  | 12/13/13      | 11/12/14      |
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

Now I need a third field in the same query to compare the results of the first two fields and show which is the MAX of those two.
I have column 2 and 3 in the query; how can I take that and create column 4 in the same query?

```
Example Query:  
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | Max Dues_Date | Max Cont_Date | Max Date(DD&CD) |  
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 01/01/15      | 09/12/11      | 01/01/15        |  
| 2  | 07/30/14      | 06/20/13      | 07/30/14        |
| 3  | 02/11/13      | 09/16/14      | 09/16/14        |  
| 4  | 07/30/12      | 06/20/11      | 07/30/12        |  
| 5  | 12/13/13      | 11/12/14      | 11/12/14        |  
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adapting this to your own scenario:

```
SELECT tblTest.DueDate, tblTest.ContDate, [DueDate]-[ContDate] AS Test,  IIf([Test]<0,[ContDate],[DueDate]) AS MaxRes
FROM tblTest;
```

"Test" finds which is the later date, ContDate or Due Date. The IIf statement selects the later date.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes!  I was able to adapt this and it works great!  (just had to add in "nz" to replace null values)
Thank you!